# How to split age column which is currently in range into different age category in python

Tags: data-cleaning

Currently I am using suicide rates overview.csv data from kaggle.
I have an age column in which ages are into range.
I want to categorize them into a specific age category so that i could use that for data pre-processing.

dataset['age'] -

age
15-24
35-54
55-74
75+

Is there anyone who would like to help me out what i am supposed to do with this age group so that it won't display error i.e '<' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'str'?

while using standardscaler
It throws an error i.e could not convert string to float: '25-34'

Comment: You can use pd.cut. Check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34165876/trying-to-create-grouped-variable-in-python